# Scanning a disk for files quickly with progress bar

Tags: macos, cocoa, filesystems

I need to search a folder (and all sub folders) for certain files. This needs to be done as quickly as possible and I need to be able to display a progress indicator to the user.

To display a progress indicator I would need to quickly retrieve, for example, the total number of folders underneath my folder being searched. That way I can count the sub folders as I scan them and report something useful back to the user.

Is this information available somewhere?

Note that this functionality is specifically for disks that aren't indexed using Spotlight. For Spotlight indexed drives I just run an NSMetadataQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use NSDirectoryEnumarator for that?

You can have your total number of files to check on enumerator and then you just update your progress bar while iterating.

Here's a small piece of code checking all sub folders. It already checks if URL is a directory ,so you can just ignore it.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init] ;
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLIsDirectoryKey];
NSString *path = @"YOUR PATH HERE"
NSMutableArray *files = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager
                                     enumeratorAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
                                     includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                     options:0
                                     errorHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                                         // Handle the error.
                                         // Return YES if the enumeration should continue after the error.
                                         return YES;
                                     }];

for (NSURL *url in enumerator) {
    NSError *error;
    NSNumber *isDirectory = nil;
    if (! [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:&error]) {
        // handle error
        NSLog(@"error-%@", error );
    }
    else if (! [isDirectory boolValue]) {
        //CHECK FOR YOUR FILES ON THIS URL AND UPDATE PROGRESS INDICATOR            
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to know how far I am through the scan of the disk I have to know how many folders there are to scan...

Comment: You are looking for files or directories? `[[enumerator  allObjects] count]` gives you how many files ( & directory, as they are 'files' on file system) you are looking at.

Comment: I don't know exactly what do you want to accomplish. The real number of steps you gonna make to check all files is the total number of files you need to check, not your number of folders (and sub folders).

Comment: Aww, I see your point now. I've written "skipping directories". Actually, code is not skipping directories, code is going on ALL sub folders and checking if it's directory. If it's a directory it skip (don't check if it's your file) and goes on. Just updated my answer now

Answer (score 0):

For the actual scan you can use Cocoa classes, such as `NSDirectoryEnumerator`, or lower-level facilities, such as `fts` - there are multiple ways just pick what suits you best.

The more interesting part is your progress indicator. The file system does not maintain a "child" count for a folder, i.e. a count of all the children, grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc. However the number of files on a whole volume is available, e.g. see `statfs`.

The number of items in a particular folder is quick and easy to determine; e.g. `NSFileManager`'s `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` returns an array, the `fts` routines return a linked list, and you can even work it out use the hard link count - obtainable via `NSURL`'s `getResourceValue:forKey:error:`. Using such methods on entry to a directory you can add its child count to a total, so as you scan the tree you maintain both the number of items processed and the currently known number that need to be processed. Your UI can be of the form "n of m" where both can increase.

If you don't like that then the number of items in a whole tree requires (pre)scanning the tree, which takes a certain amount of time (you can see this in the Finder - just select any folder, the closer to the root of the disk the better, and do a Get Info and you will see a pause while the information is collected). It is not hard to do this using any of the scanning methods mentioned above. You have to consider the time/value/memory tradeoff - e.g. while you can say produce a list of *all* the items in the tree (a directory enumerator will give you that) count it and then process it one item at a time you risk having a large memory footprint and a pause before anything at all happens - like the pause you see in the Finder's Get Info window).

So your goal of "quickly with progress bar" is a challenge.

HTH

Comment: The problem is that I actually need to scan for all bundles on the system matching a given pattern. Bundles are folders, so if I have to prescan to get the folder count then I may as well do the scan at the same time.

Comment: @tarmes - that is a reasonable conclusion. Consider the "n of m" type of UI, while you can keep increasing the limit of a graphical progress indicator the backward moving progress-so-far can be confusing. Alternatively take the count of items on the volume as your upper limit, then you tend to under report progress if you are only scanning a folder rather than a whole disc.